# PHP reserved keywords allowed in namespace? (public, private, default)

Tags: php, namespaces, phpstorm, keyword, psr-4

PhpStorm is highlighting the following namespace as an error.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Public;
```

Error: `Expected: identifier`

In general. Are reserved keywords like `public`, `function`, `class` not acceptable for namespacing?

Comment: Follow the links in this http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php where http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php does state `Public` as being one where it states *"....except that class may not be used as constant name."* so this may be the case.

Comment: Too bad. I hoped I could scope my web app into backend and public, namely. Seems I have to live with Frontend / Backend or something similar in that case. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. There might be a way around it, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) hints that as of PHP 7.0.0 these keywords are allowed as property, constant, and method names of classes, interfaces and traits, **except that class may not be used as constant name**, which also incorporate the requested keyword `public`.

**List of reserved keywords, which you can't use for namespacing:**

`__halt_compiler`, `abstract`, `and`, `array`, `as`, `break`, `callable`, `case`, `catch`, `class`, `clone`, `const`, `continue`, `declare`, `default`, `die`, `do`, `echo`, `else`, `elseif`, `empty`, `enddeclare`, `endfor`, `endforeach`, `endif`, `endswitch`, `endwhile`, `eval`, `exit`, `extends`, `final`, `for`, `foreach`, `function`, `global`, `goto`, `if`, `implements`, `include`, `include_once`, `instanceof`, `insteadof`, `interface`, `isset`, `list`, `namespace`, `new`, `or`, `print`, `private`, `protected`, `public`, `require`, `require_once`, `return`, `static`, `switch`, `throw`, `trait`, `try`, `unset`, `use`, `var`, `while`, `xor`

A potential workaround to fix this issue is to **add an extra character to the word** or **use the plural form of the word**. Another opportunity would be to go one level up in the namespace and **use the keyword as a prefix** `PublicFooController`. *(or even suffix, if you prefer that)*

My intention was to scope my web app into `public` (for guests and visitors) and `private` (for private needs) area.
I went for `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend` and `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend` instead of trying to incorperate the words `public` and `private` in to my namespacing, even if I personally think these generally fits better to my needs, because both have frontend and backend. But... Anyway, this keeps me off having trouble organizing my files and namespaces the way I would do, when I would use `public` and `private`.

Comment: *"I went for namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend and..."* You could go for `Admin` and `Site` (or alike) as an alternative. Or perhaps give names to your back end and front end and use them.

Comment: I called them General (Public) and Restricted (Private).

Comment: I'd suggest `open` = `public`, and `close` = `private` as alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

In PHP 8 this has changed. Namespaces are now single tokens and can contain reserved words. Here is an RFC available at https://wiki.php.net/rfc/namespaced_names_as_token